# The sentence structure containing a relative pronoun indicating the indirect object in the clause

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, indirect-objects, predicate-frames

When you want to indicate an indirect object with a relative pronoun, you might change the sentence structure from "verb + IO + DO" to "verb + DO + to IO. But this conversion may be unnecessary. Which is comfortable, acceptable or wrong among the sentences below? Does it depend on formality? Let me know what you think.

1. There were two healthcare workers who I handed the paperwork to.
2. There were two healthcare workers who I handed the paperwork.
3. There were two healthcare workers to whom I handed the paperwork.

IO: indirect object
DO: direct object

---

As John kindly commented, it may depend on the verb. Therefore I added two more sentences below.

4. There were two healthcare workers that I gave the paperwork.
5. There were two healthcare workers that I gave the paperwork to.

Comment: (1) is the preferable one. (3) is also acceptable, though fussy. (2) is ungrammatical, because _hand_ requires at least a _to_ to indicate the receiver. You could possibly just get away with (4) _There were two healthcare workers that I gave the paperwork._ Though a _to_ would be much better at the end of (4).

Comment: @JohnLawler though I might say *"There were two healthcare workers, so I handed them the paperwork."*

Comment: @243 The simple answer is that an indirect object cannot be relativised.

Comment: Yes, unless it's promoted to direct object (by Dative, for example) first.